# What are possible values for bundleobject.getExtras().get(String key)?

Tags: android, string, android-intent, bundle

I seen this code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

And it got my data and everything worked but I didn't quite understand why. Is the key parameter in the bundleobject.getExtras().get(String key) should be one of some constant values or it is something that depends on me? I tried to change the name of the intent object (data) and it still worked.

Thanks from advanced :)

Comment: "data" is the same key used in one of the flavors of Bundle.put(). As long as the keys are same, you should be able to get whatever you have put.

Answer (score 0):

so [`getExtras()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) is a public method of `Intent` class. It will return a `Bundle` object. You do anything with this object.

Answer (score 0):

The key is from whoever created the bundle. Looks like you are returning a value from an activity, so whatever activity you are returning from packs the bundle with both a "key" and a "value."

So they key doesn't have to be a constant value, but it isn't calculated, you must be explicitly looking for it. The value can be any data type, and you should know what kind you are expecting ahead of time.